# Get Html code from string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

In my Asp.net View I want to transform a string to a html code knowing that the string is expressed as an html helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text_actualite)
```

for example
 `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text_actualite)` contain "**i example /i**"
I want to display example in *italic* format.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) like this:

`@Html.Raw(modelItem.text_actualite)`